# google drive new api changes feed

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

In previous version of Android Drive Api there was a changes feed to get only changed files.
Something like that:
Changes.List request = mService.changes().list().setStartChangeId(changeId);

But in the new API (based on play services) I can't find this functionality.
Please tell me if I can use it. 
I'm porting to new API because I wan't to remove additional libraries for Drive Api to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Drive Android API doesn't currently support the [Changes methods](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes) from the REST API. If you need this functionality, you will need to continue using the [Java Client Library](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/java) for the REST API.

If you would like this functionality added to the Android API, please file a feature request describing your use case on our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request&labels=Type-Enhancement,API-DriveAndroid) to help us prioritize future development.

Comment: You can set change events though to listen for changes to files: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/events

Comment: yes I can do that. But this way I wouldn't know about new files added. As far as I see I need to remember files I already synced and put change listeners on them, add change listener to the App folder.
And I have to scan all files inside App folder after each folder change.

Comment: So you want to monitor changes to files (including additions/deletions) to files in your app folder? What are you trying to achieve by doing this? Would be great if you could file a feature request with more info.

Comment: My app use Drive as a sync service for internal files. There could be lots of files to sync. My previous algorithm was to rely on changes feed for every user device to know what changed and sync with that.

Comment: And sync process was trigerred every couple of min. I don't want to sync exactly after changes happen. I see I can snooze update event now, but what if couple of events come in those 15 min for the same file, should I process it multiple time?